# Verification of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^3}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am interested in the limit

> $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^3}$$

Can we simply conclude that:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sqrt[n]{n})^3= 1^3=1.$$
I have proven that $\sqrt[n]{n}\rightarrow1$ earlier in this textbook. Also since the limit of a power is the power of the limit.

Comment: Yes, if you already know $\sqrt[n]n\to 1$

Comment: This is a lemma the book had us prove earlier, also the limit of a power is the power of the limit.

Comment: Please include some text in your title besides just mathjax formatting.

Comment: Thanks Hagen, I do now that :)

Comment: "Also since the limit of a power is the power of the limit."  Has that been proven?  If so... you are good.  If not, you must justify it (it is true by the way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can simply do that. Since the exponent $^3$ is a constant neutral number (meaning we may interpret it as a fixed number of multiplications) we can move the limit inside of it. So if you already know $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$ then that's a full proof.

Comment: This answer is insufficient. It is not enough to state that the exponent is constant. An essential property is missing.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Raising to the power of a constant is continuous around $1$?

Comment: This is precisely the missing property. By the way, even a variable exponent would yield a continuous function.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sure you can do it with a variable exponent as well, but then you have to be extra careful. You can't put the limit inside of, say, $\sqrt[n]{n}^n$ and expect to get a sensible answer. You need a constant exponent for that (or at least an exponent converging to a nice value). And I could argue for this without continuity of exponentiation at all. Just using that $\sqrt[n]{n}^3 = \sqrt[n]{n}\cdot\sqrt[n]{n}\cdot\sqrt[n]{n}$, and you can take the limits of those separately (something which is usually proven quite early and taken as implicit).

Comment: What I mean is that "since the exponent $^3$ is constant" is not the reason.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So you're saying that I specified an unnecessarily strong property of the number $3$, and should've used a weaker one? I disagree. At any rate, I clarified somewhat. Better now?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't know it. I say $3$ is constant, you say "that's not what you're after, what you're after is that the sequence $(3)_n$ _converges_". That looks to me like you think I used a too strong property.

Answer (score 2):

Yes we are allowed to do that since for continuity

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=L\in \mathbb{R} \implies \lim_{x\to x_0} [f(x)]^k=\left[\lim_{x\to x_0} [f(x)\right]^k=L^k$$

Indeed in that particular case since $\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists \bar n \quad \forall n>\bar n \quad |\sqrt[n]{n}-1|<\epsilon$$

we have that, assuming $\sqrt[n]{n}<2$, $\forall \bar \epsilon=7\epsilon>0$

$$|(\sqrt[n]{n})^3-1|=|\sqrt[n]{n}-1|\cdot |\sqrt[n]{n^2}+\sqrt[n]{n}+1|< 7\epsilon=\bar \epsilon \quad \forall n>\bar n$$

and then $(\sqrt[n]{n})^3\to 1$.

Comment: You would need this to be an "if and only if" for this to apply here.

Comment: @WillSherwood Yes but in that case the asker was interested in that particular implication. Do you think that this is the motivation for the downvoting? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because the cubic root function is continuous, so that you can swap the limit and the root.

---

Continuity at $1$ is ensured by the fact that

$$|\sqrt[3]{1+\delta}-1|=\left|\frac{\delta}{(\sqrt[3]{1+\delta})^2+\sqrt[3]{1+\delta}+1}\right|<\frac\delta3<\epsilon$$ holds with $\delta<3\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

You know that
$\sqrt[n]{n}
\to 1$.

Also
$\sqrt[n]{n^k}
=(\sqrt[n]{n})^k
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt[n]{n^k}-1
&=(\sqrt[n]{n})^k-1\\
&=(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \sqrt[n]{n}^j\\
\text{so}\\
|\sqrt[n]{n^k}-1|
&=|(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \sqrt[n]{n}^j|\\
&=|(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)||\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \sqrt[n]{n}^j|\\
&\le|(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)|\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} |\sqrt[n]{n}^j|\\
&\le|(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)|\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} |\sqrt[n]{n}^n|\\
&=|(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)|\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} |n|\\
&=|(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)|kn\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
to make
$|\sqrt[n]{n^k}-1|
\le \epsilon$,
choose $n$ large enough
so that
$|(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)|
\le \frac{\epsilon}{kn}
$.

Answer (score 2):

You can if you know four things.

1) If $f$ is continuous and $a_n \to M$ and for all $a_n$ that $f(a_n)$ is defined and $f(M)$ is defined then $a_n\to M$ means $f(a_n) \to f(M)$.

But you *DO* have to prove this sometime.  I'm sure your text has proven that somewhere.

And

2) you need to know that $\sqrt[n]{n} \to 1$.

But you claim you have already shown that.

And 3) that $\sqrt[n]{n^3} = (\sqrt[n]{n})^3$.

Which is basic. It follows that as for all $M > 0$ and $n\in \mathbb N$ there is a unique $k = \sqrt[n]{M}$ so that $k^n = M$.  And as $(k^j)^n= (k^n)^j = M^j; for j \in \mathbb N$ it follows that $(\sqrt[n]{M})^j= \sqrt[n]{M^3}$.

And finally you need to know 4) that $()^3: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous.

Which is .... basic.  But you should have proven that sometime.

So $\lim \sqrt[n]{n^3} = \lim (\sqrt[n]{n})^3 = (\lim \sqrt[n]{n})^3 = 1^3 =1$.